# javascript get the second index same number

Tags: javascript

! P.S: I need only this response don't complete the challenge !

Hello, I have a task:
You are given num (up to 15 digits, never less than 0).

If the length of num is even, return odd numbers as ints and even ones as strings, based on their position in the given number. Strings alternate in type cases: starting in lowercase to uppercase and so on based on position. If the length of num is odd, all the rules are opposite. See sample tests.

What I did:

```js
function conv(num) {
  var numbers = {
    0: "zero",
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
    5: "five",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eight",
    9: "nine"
  }
  var final_arr = [];
  var lengt = num.toString();
  if (lengt.length % 2 === 0) {
    var spl = lengt.split("");
    for (var i in spl) {
      if (Number(spl[i]) % 2 === 1) {
        final_arr.push(Number(spl[i]));
      } else if (Number(spl[i]) % 2 === 0) {
        var the_index = spl.indexOf(spl[i]) + 1;
        var conv = numbers[spl[i]].split("").splice(0,
          the_index).join("");
        final_arr.push(conv);
      }
    }
  }
  return final_arr.join("");
}
console.log(conv(47309534));
```

The result is `f73zero953f`  expect: `f73zero953four`;

When I `console.log()`, I saw I have a problem because the second `4` get index `0` too, that's why I get only `f`, how to get the second `4` index (`7`).

! P.S: I need only this response don't complete the challenge !

Comment: You don't need to use `indexOf()`. `i` is the index.

Comment: Why are you splicing anything? There's nothing in the task description that says you're supposed to use a substring. Also, strings have a `substring()` function, you don't need to split to an array, slice it, then join back to a string.

Comment: Why are you testing if `Number(spl[i])` is odd or even. The task says "based on their position in the given number", so it means odd or even positions, not digit values.

Comment: So you just need to test `if (i % 2 == 0) { do even thing } else { do odd thing }`